# How can I set Cassandra primary key?

Tags: cassandra

I specify 2 unique data types, but when one of them is different, it keeps adding records.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The table schema has a **compound primary key**, i.e. it is composed of a partition key (`username`) and clustering key (`email`). This means that each partition has one or more rows of emails.

It is a completely different schema to a table with just a **simple primary key** (only has a partition key, no clustering key) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_username (
    username text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
```

This table would only ever have one row in each partition. Cheers!

[UPDATE] If you want your table to be partitioned by BOTH `username` + `email`, you need to create a new table which has a **composite partition key** (partition key has two or more columns):

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_username_email (
    username text,
    email text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ( (username, email) )
)
```

Note the difference: BOTH columns are enclosed in a bracket so they are treated as one key.

Comment: Currently I have set username and mail as primary key, but I cannot use or in SQL query.

Comment: I'm aware of that. It's what I said in my answer. 

Comment: So how can I achieve this? So how can I use the " || " operator? :)
For example, if there is a username or email, it should not add a record.

Comment: You can't do that based on your table's schema.

Comment: So how do we check both the username and the e-mail address at the same time, there must be a way, right? :/

Comment: That's not the question you asked. I've updated my answer accordingly. You need to be specific with your question otherwise you won't get the answer you're after.

Comment: Yes, I gave wrong information. What I mean is how can I query the username or email account separately?

Your update allows us to query the username and email address at the same time.